# Como faço para enviar vários valores para uma única Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Tenho 4 telas (Activity), são elas: MainActivity, DisiplinaActivity, AvaliacaoActivity e ResultadoFinalActivity.

A questão é, os dados coletados das telas DisiplinaActivity e AvaliacaoActivity retornam para a MainActivity e depois são enviados para a ResultadoFinalActivity.

Minha dúvida é: como faço para enviar esses dados através de chave,valor? Até agora tenho esse código, onde recebo os valores, mas não sei como enviar eles para a tela final.

Alguém já pegou algo assim ou consegue me dar uma luz?

Agradeço

```
public void proximaTela(View v) { 
    Intent enviarDados = null;   

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnDisciplina:
            enviarDados = new Intent(this, DisciplinaActivity.class);
            enviarDados.putExtra("disciplina", disciplina);
            startActivityForResult(enviarDados, Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_DADOS_DISCIPLINA);
            break;

        case R.id.btnAvalicao1:
            enviarDados = new Intent(this, AvaliacaoActivity.class);
            enviarDados.putExtra("avaliacao1", disciplina);
            startActivityForResult(enviarDados, Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_DADOS_AVALIACAO);
            break;

        case R.id.btnAvalicao2:
            enviarDados = new Intent(this, AvaliacaoActivity.class);
            enviarDados.putExtra("avaliacao2", disciplina);
            startActivityForResult(enviarDados, Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_DADOS_AVALIACAO2);
            break;

        case R.id.telaResultado:
            enviarDados = new Intent(this, ResultadoActivity.class);
            break;

        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Problema ao enviar ou receber dados!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_DADOS_DISCIPLINA){
            Bundle params = data.getExtras();
            String disciplina = params.getString("nomeDisciplina");
            String professor = params.getString("nomeProfessor");
        }else if (requestCode == Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_DADOS_AVALIACAO){
            Bundle params = data.getExtras();
            String avaliacao1 = params.getString("tituloAvl1");
            Double nota1 = params.getDouble("notaAvl1");
        }else if (requestCode == Constantes.REQUEST_CODE_DADOS_AVALIACAO2){
            Bundle params = data.getExtras();
            String avalicao2 = params.getString("tituloAvl2");
            Double nota2 = params.getDouble("notaAvl2");
        }
    }

}
```

Botão Salvar da tela DisciplinaActivity

public void btnSalvar(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("nomeDisciplina", editnomeDisciplina.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("nomeProfessor", editNomeProfessor.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();
    }

Comment: Não compreendi este `switch`. Parece que possui um botão para 4 telas. São dados únicos? Apenas uma disciplina, apenas um professor? Ou são várias disciplinas e vários outros dados?

Comment: Exatamente, tenho 4 telas e esse switch eu utilizei para redirecionar através do Id das Activitys. Por exemplo, a tela de DisciplinaActivity tem os campos "nomeDisciplina" e "nomeProfessor", ao clicar por exemplo no botão "Salvar" ela retorna pra MainActivity já com os dados em uma Intent, certo? Assim segue pra tela da AvaliacaoActivity. No final das contas, tenho dados das duas Activitys na MainActivity e preciso enviar ela pra tela final de resultado usando Intent..

Não sei se fui claro, rsrsr

Comment: Ainda não compreendi, no final do `onClick` do botão salvar você coloca extras na intent e chama o `finish()`?

Comment: Coloquei o código do botão salvar

Comment: Então seria este fluxo: `MainActivity.class > DisciplinaActivity.class > MainActivity.class > AvaliacaoActivity.class > MainActivity.class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como faço para enviar esses dados através de chave,valor?

Assim como um [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) faz?

```
private void iniciarActivityBundle(Bundle bundle, Class<?> cls) {
    // Supondo que este método está em uma activity, this é o contexto
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Use-o quando for passar dados para uma activity dessa forma:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("nomeDisciplina", "valor");
//bundle.putString("chave", "valor");
//bundle.putInt("chave", 0);
// ...

iniciarActivityBundle(bundle, ResultadoFinalActivity.class);
```

Na ResultadoFinalActivity, o mais cedo possível dentro do `onCreate`:

```
receberBundle(getIntent());
```

Na ResultadoFinalActivity, fora do `onCreate`, declare:

```
private void receberBundle(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String nomeDisciplina = extras.getString("nomeDisciplina");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nomeDisciplina)) {
            // ...
        }
    } else {
        // Não recebemos dados
        // Se for possível continuar a activity, faça, se não, aborte com finish();
    }
}
```